# form validation- validate inputs dynamically created by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to do form validation with Angular. I am able to validate the input elements as follows,

```
<tr ng-repeat="answer in answers track by $index" ng-form="subQuestionForm">
    <td>
        <div>
            <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' :((subQuestionForm.ansText.$invalid && isSubmitted) || ((subQuestionForm.ansText.$invalid && subQuestionForm.ansText.$dirty))}">
                <input name="ansText" id="ansText" type='text' ng-model="answer.ansText" class="form-control" required />
                <div class="error,help-block col-md-offset-4" ng-show="((subQuestionForm.lhsText.$dirty  || isSubmitted) && ( subQuestionForm.lhsText.$invalid))">
                    <h6 class="help-block" ng-if="subQuestionForm.lhsText.$error.required">Enter  answer</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

this will validate the form such that the user has to enter all the answer(i.e enter into all the textbox created), but i want that the user should enter 2 or more . if only one answer is entered then the error message will show otherwise the form is valid. 
I tried doing this by taking index for each but failed.
anyone can throw some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="answer in answers track by $index" ng-form="subQuestionForm">
    <td>
       <div>
        <input name="ansText" id="ansText" type='text' ng-model="answer.ansText" class="form-control" ng-required="$index == 0 || $index == 1 " />
            </div>    
    </td>
</tr>
```